# Reduce to Wallis formula

Tags: limits, infinite-product

How do we get   [Wallis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WallisFormula.html)
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=\lim_{l\to\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{l+1}\frac{(2j)(2j)}{(2j-1)(2j-1)} $$

from
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n+\frac{3}{2}} \bigg[\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2})}\bigg]^2=1$$

Comment: Interesting. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: See [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: There was a typo in your Wallis Formula: one of the factors in the denominator should be $(2j + 1)$. I wonder if that's why you couldn't derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a formula for the Gamma function of one-half increment from an integer:$$\Gamma(n + \frac{3}2) = \Gamma\left( (n + 1) +\frac{1}2 \right) = \frac{ (2n+1)!! }{ 2^{n+1} }\sqrt{\pi} = \frac{ (2n+1) (2n-1)(2n-3)\ldots 5\cdot 3 \cdot 1}{ 2^{n+1} }\sqrt{\pi} $$
See for example [Eq.(58) of this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

Thus it's rather straightforward from here:
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{ \Gamma( n+1 ) }{ \Gamma(n + \frac{3}2) } &= \frac{ 2 }{ \sqrt{\pi} }\frac{ 2^n \cdot n! }{ (2n + 1)!! }  \qquad\text{, each 2 goes to each term of $n!$}\\
\left( \frac{ \Gamma( n+1 ) }{ \Gamma(n + \frac{3}2) } \right)^2 &= \frac{ 2 }{ \pi }\cdot 2\cdot \left( \frac{ 2^n \cdot n! }{ (2n + 1)!! } \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{ 2 }{ \pi }\cdot \frac{2}{2n + 1} \left[ \frac{2n \cdot 2n }{ (2n+1) (2n-1) } \frac{2(n-1) \cdot 2(n-1) }{ (2n-1) (2n-3) }\ldots \frac{4\cdot 4}{5\cdot3} \frac{2\cdot 2}{3\cdot1}\frac{1}{1} \right]\\
&= \frac{ 2 }{ \pi }\cdot \frac{2}{2n + 1} \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{(2j)(2j)}{(2j+1)(2j-1)}
\end{align}$$
$$\implies\frac{(n+1)^2}{n+\frac{3}{2}} \left( \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2})}\right)^2 = \frac{ 2 }{ \pi }\cdot \left[ \frac{2}{2n + 1}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n+\frac{3}{2}} \right]\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{(2j)(2j)}{(2j+1)(2j-1)} $$
Upon taking the limit $n \to \infty$, the square bracket becomes unity and you have the Wallis formula.